# reproduce Cloud Run's disk and memory limits in Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I'd like to reproduce on my local development machine in Docker the disk and memory limits that Cloud Run sets for my container in Cloud Run. How can I configure my local Docker to set the same disk and memory limits for my container as Cloud Run does?

I'm running a Cloud Run service with a 4 GB memory limit. In Cloud Run, the output of `df -h` is :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            2.0G   36K  2.0G   1% /
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

I'm guessing that the 4GB memory limit is split 50/50 between the in-memory
file system `/` and RAM `/dev/shm` (?). Is this correct?

If so, how can I set a 2GB memory limit and a 2GB disk limit in Docker?

Does `docker run --memory=2g --memory-swap=2g` set the memory limit to 2GB?

How to set the disk limit?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation on [setting memory limits](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-limit-cpu-and-memory-usage-in-docker-containers-a024b429f55e#:%7E:text=%2D%2Dcpus%3D2-,Memory%20Limits,-Memory%20limits%20can), you can either use the `--memory` or `--memory-swap` parameter. It is recommended to **only** use `--memory` as `--memory-swap` will use the available storage space that may lead to slowdowns or crashes.

Your syntax should look like this:

```
sudo docker run -it --memory="[memory_limit]" [docker_image]
```

Additional information can be found through this link on [setting maximum memory access](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-memory-and-cpu-limit#:%7E:text=Set%20Maximum%20Memory%20Access).

If you're accessing it through Cloud Run, you could access it through this [enter link description here](https://console.cloud.google.com/run?_ga=2.43300005.1076701393.1677160784-1296106709.1677160772), select your Cloud Run Service, then click `EDIT & DEPLOY NEW REVISION`.

Minimum memory will depend whether you're using first or second generation:

- 128 MiB for first generation
- 512 MiB for second generation

The maximum amount of memory you can configure is 32 gibibyte (`32 Gi`).

Click the **Container** tab and select your desired memory from the **Memory** dropdown list. Click **Deploy** afterwards.

You can check this documentation for additional information on [setting and updating memory limits](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits#setting).